# How to do Django Rest Framework double nested serializer

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build an api that have an endpoint which in the POST receives the JSON like bellow:

```
{
   "title":"Quiz 1",
   "questions":[
      {
         "description":"Question 1?",
         "answers":[
            {
               "description":"Answer 1",
               "true_or_false":true
            },
                      {
               "description":"Answer 2",
               "true_or_false":false
            }
         ]
      },
         {
         "description":"Question 2?",
         "answers":[
            {
               "description":"Answer 1",
               "true_or_false":true
            },
                      {
               "description":"Answer 2",
               "true_or_false":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But I don't know how to build the serializers for double nested fields, like a list of answers within a question and a list of questions within a quiz. The code I made so far is below:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=False)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name='questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    true_or_false = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

views.py

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer


class AnswerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer


class QuizViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer


class OnlyQuizViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Quiz.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return queryset
    
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['id', 'description', 'true_or_false']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id','description','answers']
        read_only_fields = ('quiz',)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        answers_data = validated_data.pop('answers')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for answer in answers_data:
            Answer.objects.create(question=question, **answer)
        return question


class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'questions']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for questions in questions_data:
            Question.objects.create(quiz=quiz, **questions)
        return quiz
```

With the above serializers, I'm getting the error below:

```
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use answers.set() instead.
```

So what's the right way to build double-nested serializers? So far I haven't been able to find anything to help me

Comment: when do you get this error ? what operation are you doing ? (GET/POST) and to which endpoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you get that error when you try posting to the Quiz api, you'll have a problem when you want to create a question

```py
Question.objects.create(quiz=quiz, **questions)
```

since this question also includes a list of answers that needs to be created first.

Try using the serializer you already have like this

```py
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'questions']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for questions in questions_data:
            question_serializer = QuestionSerializer({**questions, "quiz": quiz}) # might need to send quiz.id instead
            question_serializer.is_valid()
            question_serializer.save()
        return quiz
```

and update your `QuestionSerializer` to use `AnswerSerializer` the same way (or you can create Answers explicitly there)

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem, I just had to add question_serializer.is_valid() after the QuestionSerilizer declaration

Comment: @MatheusBachisteLopes nice catch ! I've updated the answer to include that